# Problem using Flask to connect Python script to Expo React Native App

Tags: python, react-native, flask, expo

Keep receiving error:

> [TypeError: Network request failed], when I try read data to expo app from >Python file.

Attempt in React App:

```js
    const [data, setData] = useState([ ]); // Initialize data as an empty array

    useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch data from backend
        fetch("http://localhost:5000/users")
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            setData(data);
            console.log("Fetched data:", data); // Log the fetched data
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
          });
      }, []);
```

and I believe you have to add to `'package.json': "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"`.

Comment: Check your network tab: "Network request failed" means exactly what it says - that there was a network request and it failed. The network tab would be the first port of call to see what sort of error it was. The error should mean that there is no such endpoint or maybe not even such a service. It's not really clear how/where you're running the server, whether it runs on the port you've specified and so on. It *might* and then the error would be that the server is somehow unreachable (then you have to investigate why) or maybe it's not even running or not on that port.